# How to export dbisam image records to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, image, dbisam

I have a dbisam database that I am trying to export the images that are contained in one of the tables. There is a single record export available when you double click on the (memo) type when you display the table and that works fine. But I have not found a way to export all of the images in any kind of batch mode that works for the images.  I have created an dbisam odbc driver and pulled the table into SQL Server with the SQL Server import wizard and that seems to work, but in comparing the size of the single export record size and the wizard  image size, it is now double what the single record export is and these are unable to be opened.

Any suggestions? Using SQL Server 2017 import wizard and dbisam 4.8. I have tried mapping to different types with no difference in outcomes.

Comment: You need to include more information, such as a sample table schema or two. Doubling of size suggests you're trying to insert binary image data into `nvarchar` or `ntext` columns instead of something like `varbinary(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with "elevate software" they indicated that this column  was incorrectly  setup as a memo to store images should have been setup as a BLOB type instead to properly work with images and scans.  I copied the needed columns into a new temp table and altered the memo type to BLOB in the new table so as not to disrupt the old table.  I then exported this table to mssql via the mssql import export wizard and the images came across correctly.  I used an ssis job to then extract those to individual files and can view and work with the images as needed.  I hope this might help someone else as well.